# CUDA 7.5 install on Mac missing nvrtc

Tags: cuda, gpu

According to the documentation, when I install the CUDA 7.5 Toolkit on my Mac (OSX 10.11) I should get the nvrtc files with it.  I do not.  Where do I pick up the nvrtc header files and libraries?  Were they supposed to be in the bundle and left out?  Were the deprecated or replaced with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the trick is:

1) Install XCode (from the App Store) FIRST.  After the App Store is done installing it, you have to go into your Application menu and actually run it and accept the license.

2) Use the Homebrew version:

```
$  brew install Caskroom/cask/cuda
```

3) Lastly, you can update your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to find the new code:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

For some reason, simply downloading the package from NVidia and installing it does not get you a complete installation.

Comment: The [mac installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#abstract) should be a good resource.  It points out the need for installing XCode first.