# Installing cuda via brew and dmg

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, dmg

After attempting to install nvidia toolkit on MAC by following guide : http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#axzz4FPTBCf7X I received error "Package manifest parsing error"  which led me to this : [NVidia CUDA toolkit 7.5.27 failing to install on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942135/nvidia-cuda-toolkit-7-5-27-failing-to-install-on-os-x) . I unmounted the dmg and upshot was that instead of receiving "Package manifest parsing error" the installer would not launch (it seemed to launch briefly , then quit).

Installing via command `brew install Caskroom/cask/cuda` ([CUDA 7.5 install on Mac missing nvrtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105066/cuda-7-5-install-on-mac-missing-nvrtc/36180729)) seems to have successfully installed cuda.

command `nvcc --version`  returns :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Apr_11_13:23:40_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.26
```

I've built the example in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples/1_Utilities` with :

```
make -C bandwidthTest/
```

This executed without error.

It appears installing with `brew install Caskroom/cask/cuda` is safe method of installing ? What is difference between this install method and installing via DMG file from nvidia ?

Caskroom appears to be an extension for brew for installing GUI applications : https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask

Should an IDE also be installed as part of the cuda install ?

Comment: Nsight Eclipse Edition is part of the CUDA Toolkit Installer for Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods download and install from the same .dmg file from NVidia.

The homebrew-cask framework is the preferred method for installing software distributed as binaries in the homebrew paradigm.

This is my understanding.

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays you have to do the following to install cuda via brew:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-drivers
brew cask install nvidia-cuda
```

See https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/38325 .
Then you also need to add the following to your file `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.0/lib${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html.

**UPDATE**: Newer versions of Mac OS X with activated SIP (System integrity protection) will prevent modifying the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/waugt62RQMU). You can check that via

```
source ~/.bash_profile
env | grep DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If the output of this command is empty SIP is active and you might want to deactivate it as described at https://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html . After doing this you should see

```
env | grep DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.0/lib
```

Comment: [macOS 10.14 (Mojave) does not support CUDA](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042279/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-10-and-macos-10-14/). Cask nvidia-cuda depends on macOS release being one of [10.12, 10.13].

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work with Catalina: `Error: macOS Sierra or High Sierra is required`

Answer (score 2):

Using DMG file, follow below:

```
wget 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.2.89_mac.dmg' && \
hdiutil attach cuda_10.2.89_mac.dmg \
    -nobrowse \
    -mountpoint \
    /Volumes/CUDAMacOSXInstaller
```

Open installer:

```
open /Volumes/CUDAMacOSXInstaller/CUDAMacOSXInstaller.app
```

Uncheck "CUDA Samples" before continue.

Unmount and remove file:

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/CUDAMacOSXInstaller && rm ./cuda_10.2.89_mac.dmg
```